# Replacing strings in BeautifulSoup iterator exits early?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup 4 to try and iterate over a list of strings and replace substrings, but I'm having a problem where performing a `replace_with` while iterating over the `strings` generator exits the loop early.

For example, given this code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = BeautifulSoup("<p>a</p><p>b</p><p>c</p>", features="html.parser")
for st in s.strings:
  st.replace_with('replace')
```

The final content of `s` will be `<p>replace</p><p>b</p><p>c</p>`, while the expected behavior would be for a, b and c each to be replaced. Stepping through with a debugger confirms that iteration over `strings` halts after the replace has occurred, basically performing only one iteration and exiting early.

In practice I will be updating subsections of the strings and replacing them with newly created BeautifulSoup objects, so simpler replace methods might not work:

```
updated = st.replace(keyword, f'<a href="url/{keyword}">{keyword}</a>')
st.replace_with(BeautifulSoup(updated, features="html.parser"))
```

Is there a workaround or more correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure why the `replace_with()` interrupts the generator, but assuming the list of strings is not huge, one possible workaround is to get all values of it at once with `list()`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = BeautifulSoup("<p>a</p><p>b</p><p>c</p>", features="html.parser")

for st in list(s.strings):
    st.replace_with("replace")

print(s)
```

Result:

```html
<p>replace</p><p>replace</p><p>replace</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this output b'coz, as explained in the documentation for [replace_with()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with)

> PageElement.replace_with() removes a tag or string from the tree, and
>   replaces it with the tag or string of your choice

Once removed from the tree it no longer has a [next_element](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-element-and-previous-element) and the generator exits early. We can examine this using this code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = BeautifulSoup("<p>a</p><p>b</p><p>c</p>", features="html.parser")
for st in s.strings:
    print(st.next_element)
    st.replace_with('replace')
    print(st)
    print(st.next_element)
```

Output

```
<p>b</p>
a
None
```

After `replace_with()` the `next_element` is `None`.

One approach would be that mentioned by @cody ie. to get all values of the values at once with list().

Another approach is to store the `next_element` and set it back after `replace_with()` to let the generator yield more elements.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = BeautifulSoup("<p>a</p><p>b</p><p>c</p>", features="html.parser")
for st in s.strings:
    next=st.next_element
    st.replace_with('replace')
    st.next_element=next
print(s)
```

Output

```
<p>replace</p><p>replace</p><p>replace</p>
```